# What is the measure of X?

Tags: geometry

[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnHP.png)

In the circle, BC is a diameter. What is the measure of X?

Comment: Do you know the inscribed angle theorem

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since arc AB is 135 degrees, and BC is a diameter, arc BC is 180- 135= 145 degrees and angle c is 145/2= 72.5 degrees.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: First, arc $BC$ is $180^\circ$. Second, $180-135\ne 145$. Third, $\angle C = 67.5^\circ$.